# New Linux User, Where do I begin and how do I master the OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am fairly new to the Linux OS. I'm being asked to learn the OS (`Ubuntu & Fedora`) for computational science purposes.

The problem isn't getting involved or into the OS, but I don't exactly know what path to take in terms of delving deep. So far I've played around with the Terminal (e.g. issuing commands to create basic `FORTRAN` or `C++` files, moving, deleting, copying, creating directories).

I feel all of this is basic and that I'm missing so much more. I've searched online for various documentations, but I feel at a loss because I don't understand what path I am supposed to be taking. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Most learning is driven by necessity. It's kind of hard to say what you will and won't find useful. Your best bet is to pick a series of small projects and try to do them. Once you have a reference point you can ask questions that aren't so broad.

Comment: You can check this course on edx: https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-linux-linuxfoundationx-lfs101x-0

Answer (score 1):

Installing and configuring Arch Linux would be a good next step if you're comfortable with basic terminal commands. The documentation on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide)  (both for the installation, and the distro in general) is famously good.

If you go down this path, it's best to use a virtual machine or a clean computer so that you can experiment safely.

The vast majority of what you learn will apply to other distributions, so I wouldn't worry that it's not Ubuntu or Fedora.